# How to make vuepress dynamically create the side navigation?

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I'm trying to simplify the creation of my view press site so I don't have to add entries on the left side navigation manually.

So far I tried

```
    "vuepress-auto-sidebar": "^1.1.1"
```

But it renders the `.git` and `node_modules` folder as well.  It also does not render the title.

[image]

Not only that it does not render a file called `upload.md` in the root of my project.

I am thinking I may just have to code it manually by doing some form of directory scanning (though I am not sure how to "watch" that, so that it updates when I add new files).

The way I worked around it so far is to configure theme-config to do this which removes the errant modules.

```
    sidebar: sidebar
      .getSidebar()
      .filter((v) => v.path !== "/node_modules/" && v.path !== "/.git/"),
```

Then add filters to it skips `.git` and `node_modules` folders.  Following that I have to parse the Markdown to extract the title.

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow ? :)

Comment: It helps but it shows the flaw of the plugin but I did find another plugin that did most of what I needed.

Comment: Same plugin as the one I've linked. ^^

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: usually, you do write your `.md` docs into a `docs` directory (not at the root of the project) and then launch it with this (from `package.json`)

```
vuepress dev docs --no-clear-screen --open
```

---

As for the sidebar, my first answer is below.

From this github issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/613

You can see that this is not available out of the box. So, you could use some solutions given there and generate it kinda yourself but you could also try this npm package called [vuepress-bar](https://github.com/ozum/vuepress-bar).

It is working great ! Beware tho, I had some incompatibility issues with it after upgrading to Nuxt 2.15.2, not sure if it's still the case but this way pretty annoying to not being able to run vuepress at all.

Answer (score 0):

I chose a different plugin `vuepress-bar` in the end but still had to implement the filter

```
const getConfig = require("vuepress-bar");
const { nav, sidebar } = getConfig();
module.exports = {
  themeConfig: {
    nav,
    sidebar: sidebar.filter(i => i.title !== "Node Modules"),
    smoothScroll: true
  }
};
```